# Executable JAR with testng giving "expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency."

Tags: java, spring, maven, executable-jar

Through maven command everything is fine and tests are running good.
I am creating an executable jar which will except same arguments and run the testng tests.

I am using assembly plugin to create the executable jar with my main method class.

When running through jar

```
java -jar <jar name>.jar
```

Getting following error.

> **Caused by**:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name '**apiClientFacade**' defined in
>   com.test.framework.**TestContext**: Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor argument with **index 0** of type
>   [com.test.framework.configuration.**TestConfiguration**]: :
>   No qualifying bean of type
>   [com.test.framework.configuration.TestConfiguration]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.test.framework.configuration.**TestConfiguration**]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:

Related JAVA files

**TestContext.java**

```
@Configuration
@Import({EmbeddedContext.class, FullDataContext.class})
public class TestContext {

 @Bean
 @Autowired
 @Primary
 public ApiClientFacade apiClientFacade(TestConfiguration configuration, 
 @Qualifier("apiClient") ApiClient apiClient) {
 return new ApiClientFacadeImpl(configuration, apiClient);
 }
}
```

**TestConfiguration.java**

```
@Component     
public class TestConfiguration { }
```

**ApiClientFacadeImpl.java**

```
 @Component
    public class ApiClientFacadeImpl implements ApiClientFacade {
}
```

**ApiClientFacade.java**

```
public interface ApiClientFacade {}
```

Comment: Perhaps the _com.test.framework.configuration_ package is not scanned by Spring? Add [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation to your main class and specify the package names to scan for it.

Comment: Tried @ComponentScan with packages. Its not working, giving same error.